# Records without timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which has a column of datatype date.

Data was getting populated thru an API in the format 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM' from 2005 and somewhere along the years it changed to 'MM/DD/YYYY', dont know from when.

Now i need to find out when this started happening. How do I seperate the records with and without timestamp in a query?

P.S: The table is huge, millions of records, so fetching all rows and sorting wont help.

Comment: Those records *do* have a time component, it's just been set to midnight. So you should be looking at the records with `MM/DD/YYYY 00:00:00`.

Comment: maybe cast as string, and then  select  min(timestamp) where lenght(cast(timestamp as string) <=10 or whatever is the length of MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: @MiloBellano A `DATE` datatype **always** has both date and time components - if a value is inserted as just the year to day components then the hour to second components will default to midnight (`00:00:00`). Casting the date to a string will just make an implicit call to `TO_CHAR` using the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter as the format model - and that will format all the dates identically regardless of whether the time component is midnight or not.

Answer (score 4):

This will find the latest date which is not at midnight:

```
SELECT MAX(
         CASE
           WHEN your_column > TRUNC( your_column )
           THEN your_column
         END
       )
FROM   your_table
```

Answer (score 3):

The trunc(date) function removes the time part of a date. For records with a time trunc(date)<>date and for records without a time trunc(date)=date.

```
select * 
from your_table
where trunc(date_column)=date_column;
```

edit:

To take away any misunderstanding

```
to_date('21-07-2017','DD-MM-YYYY')
```

equals

```
to_date('21-07-2017 00:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

equals

```
trunc(to_date('21-07-2017 09:20:43','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))
```

In my words a date without time means a date without a time specified

```
to_date('21-07-2017','DD-MM-YYYY')
```

Comment: All the records have a time - it is just that some of them are always at midnight.

Comment: @Rene, I think MT0's comment is regarding your *explanation* not your suggested query. It's potentially misleading to say "records with a time" and "records without a time".

Comment: Thanks, added some extra explanation.